# How to troubleshoot default font in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-fonts

I have a flutter app targeting Android. I want to change the default font for the app but nothing seems to work.

I have added the `google_fonts` package.
I have then modified `theme` in `main.dart` `MaterialApp` as follows:

```
 MaterialApp(
    theme: ThemeData(
          textTheme: GoogleFonts.latoTextTheme(
             Theme.of(context).textTheme,
          ),
      ),
    darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
    themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
 ),
```

This doesn't work. The font does not change.

I can change individual text widget font using the below syntax and that does work:

```
  Text('Some Text',
        style: GoogleFonts.robotoMono(),
      ),
```

I have also tried downloading a font and adding it to font assets:

```
fonts:
    - family: Noto
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/NotoSans-Regular.ttf
```

Next, I referred to it in `main.dart`, but that does not work either:

```
  theme: ThemeData(
          fontFamily: 'Noto',
        ),
```

Using the below code returns `monospace`. Not sure what that is, I thought the default font should be Roboto.

```
print('font: ${DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.fontFamily}');
```

I have tried to run `flutter clean`, to uninstall the app, but none of this helps.

How can I go about troubleshooting this?

**UPDATE**

Found the problem. I was confused about the dark and light themes

Comment: Did you reference the font path in pubspec.yaml? [Docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/fonts).

Comment: I have updated the question to include the pubspec.yaml for the "download font" solution.

Comment: Okay, import all the fonts that come in the pack, not just the regular one. Import also bold, medium, regular and light.

Comment: Why do you suggest that? I don't use bold and the others and documentation says to only include the ones you need.Also, the "google fonts" method manages all the font downloads automatically and that does not work either. I do use localization, I wonder if this is not the problem...

Comment: I have some fonts in my app and localizations don't affect it, but for testing purposes, remove the localizations. With regard to all kinds of sums, it was just for the sake of conscience.

Comment: It's the dark theme settings

Answer (score 1):

please, make sure you added the:

```
void main() {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // add this before runApp
runApp(MyApp());
 }
```

it's necessary for using the font themes from the `google_fonts` package in your MaterialApp's theme property.

Comment: I already have that. My main() is async because I have some hive initialization in there. Also,  runApp(const MyApp()); as per lint suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my misunderstanding of how light and dark themes work. Anyway, posting here if anyone else made the same mistake.

So to change the default font if you are using dark theme do this:

1. Add font(s) to your `pubspec.yaml`

```
    fonts:
        - family: my font family
          fonts:
            - asset: fonts/myfontfile.ttf
```

2. Define themes in `main.dart` :

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
   brightness: Brightness.light,
   fontFamily: 'my font family'
  ),
  darkTheme: ThemeData(
   brightness: Brightness.dark,
   fontFamily: 'my font family'
  ),
  themeMode: ThemeMode.system, 
),
```